# Python - Appending new columns to Excel File based on row/cell info

Tags: python, excel, append, row

I am trying to append new columns to an excel file. But the cell value depends on the cells from the same row. I need to add about 8 columns.

Right now, based on one of the cells, let's say serialno, i do a lookup against a JSON URL and pull the relevant column info. But i need to write this info to that particular row.

So far all the help i have found shows adding 1 whole column at a time. Is that the best option or is there an easier process to add all 8 columns and keep appending row wise? I want to be careful with any blank information, as I want the cell to stay blank.

I'm a novice at this and pretty much learning and doing by available scripts.

Thanks for any direction you can provide.

Here is some code i'm currently using

```
except IndexError:
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'no' in col]
col_name = cols[0]
for x in df.index:
    n = 9 - len(str(df[col_name][x]))
    num = str(df[col_name][x]).rjust(n + len(str(df[col_name][x])), '0')
    with suppress(KeyError, UnicodeEncodeError):
        main(num)

def main(num):

for i in jsonData["people"]:
    room_no = jsonData["people"][i]["roomno"]
    title = jsonData["people"][i]["title"]
    fname = jsonData["people"][i]["full_name_ac"]
    tel = jsonData["people"][i]["telephone"]
```

Comment: Would be good to include some of your code, and example input and outout

Comment: You have a better chance of getting answers if you post your existing code showing what you've done so far or at least some examples of the data your working with.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have code for this piece. I'm stuck at conceptualizing it. Here is the JSON code i'm using to download data from JSON

    jsonData = getResponse(urlData)
    for i in jsonData["peoples"]:
        room_no = jsonData["people"][i]["roomno"]
        title = jsonData["people"][i]["title"]
        fname = jsonData["people"][i]["full_name_ac"]
        tel = jsonData["people"][i]["telephone"]
        loc = jsonData["people"][i]["location"]

Comment: You can edit your post to add the code sample and format it appropriately so it's easier to read. I personally like to use "for" loops when adding data to an Excel sheet. You can go either way you want, iterate down a column or across a row.